# Pass hostname of unix server to a .py file and .html file

Tags: python, unix

I need to get the hostname of the unix server on which the application is running(maybe store in a properties file) and then fetch that hostname value in .py file and .html file.
I need the hostname for a url which is hardcoded in the code.
url should look something like this : http://{hostname value}.nam.net/

Comment: Welcome to SO. This site is not a code-writing service and is not meant for delivering complete solutions. Users are expected to show some effort and code whilst SO is here to help you solve specific programming problems along the way. Have you tried anything already?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the UNIX servers hostname by using the socket module:

```
import socket

socket.gethostname()
```

you can then write this to your configuration file if you need it to be static, or otherwise just re-use the code in your python files when generating the hostname.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you will have a problem with what you want to do - the http://{hostname...}.nam.net will only work if you have a DNS services and something that will translate it from IP address to name.

maybe you want something like this:

```
 import socket
 def get_ip_address():
     s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
     s.connect(("8.8.8.8", 80))
     return s.getsockname()[0]
```

this will open a socket to google server and you will get back your external ip address to be used as url